# Counting elements in specified column of a .csv file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am programming in Python
I want to count how many times each word appears in a column. Coulmn 4 of my .csv file contains cca. 7 different words and need to know how many times each one appears. Eg. there are 700 lines and I need to count how many times the phrase HelloWorld appears in column 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) on the column you want. Since you mentioned it's the fourth column, you can get it by index using `iloc` as well. Of course you have to install pandas as it's not from the standard library, e.g. using pip with `pip install pandas` if you haven't already.
An example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.csv")
forth_column = df.iloc[:, 3]  # Gets all rows for the fourth column (index starts at 0)
counts = forth_column.value_counts()
print(counts)  # You'll see the number of times each string appears in the column
# The keys are the strings and the values are the number of times they appear
hello_world_counts = counts["HelloWorld"]
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome. `pandas` has many extremely useful functions and a very well written documentation which you may also find useful. Could you please mark the answer as accepted?